# wordpress: add user role on body class

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to add the user role once a user is logged in on wordpress and have the user role be in the body class=""

```
function my_class_names($classes) {
global $current_user;
$user_roles = $current_user->roles;
$user_role = array_shift($user_roles);

    if  ( is_user_logged_in() )  {
        $classes[] = $user_role;
    }
return $classes; 
} 
add_filter('body_class','my_class_names');
```

I'm not a php guy already tried research and i found [how to get the user role](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-get-the-current-logged-in-users-role?replies=10#post-1600295), and another post was [how to add body class](http://www.joelwolfgang.com/adding-a-logged-out-class-to-wordpress-body-tag/) and i'm have trouble how to get them both to work. I hope someone can help me out with this spent more than 2hrs trying to figure this out by myself :(

Comment: Two hours isn't a very long time. Traditionally we work on problems for days before resorting to asking for free assistance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change your function to this

```
function get_user_role() {
    global $current_user;
    $user_roles = $current_user->roles;
    $user_role = array_shift($user_roles);
    return $user_role;
}
```

Then, change your body tag like this

```
<body <?php body_class( get_user_role() ); ?>>
```

If the user isn't logged in, it will not add anything.

Or you can also add one more function ([from the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class))

```
add_filter('body_class','my_class_names');
function my_class_names($classes) {
    $classes[] = get_user_role();
    return $classes;
}
```

That will work.

Answer (score 8):

```
add_filter('body_class','add_role_to_body');
function add_role_to_body($classes) {
$current_user = new WP_User(get_current_user_id());
$user_role = array_shift($current_user->roles);
$classes[] = 'role-'. $user_role;
return $classes;
}
```

In my Case this code works perfectly by adding user role class to body class :)

Simply copy the code to function.php and paste it in a perfect place ;)

Comment: this is by far the cleaner way

Comment: Still works perfectly ✌️

Answer (score 4):

### WordPress 5.8 Answer:

You can easily add the current user's role as a class to the body tag by adding the following code to your functions.php file in your theme.

```
function add_user_role_to_body_classes( $classes ) {
    global $current_user;

    foreach ( $current_user->roles as $user_role ) {
        if ( is_admin() ) {
            $classes .= ' role-' . $user_role;
        } else {
            $classes[] = 'role-' . $user_role;
        }
    }

    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_user_role_to_body_classes', 100 );
add_filter( 'admin_body_class', 'add_user_role_to_body_classes', 100 );
```

### Explanation of what this code does

It retrieves the roles that this user is a part of, and adds each one to the body class. And since WordPress supports assigning multiple roles to a user, this function will print out all roles a user is a part of. Each class will be prefixed with `role-`, so a user with the Editor role would output `role-editor` to the body.

The `add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_user_role_to_body_classes', 100 );` line adds the user role class(es) to the body tag on the front-end.

The `add_filter( 'admin_body_class', 'add_user_role_to_body_classes', 100 );` line adds the user role class(es) to the body tag on the back-end (admin side of WordPress).

Answer (score 0):

You can add to the front or to the backend like so;

```
    /* Adds the user id to the admin body class array
      * Add User Role Class to Body
      * Ref https://lakewood.media/add-user-role-id-body-class-wordpress/
    */


    function print_user_classes() {
     if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
      add_filter('body_class','class_to_body');
      add_filter('admin_body_class', 'class_to_body_admin');
     }
   }
   add_action('init', 'print_user_classes');

 /// Add user role class to front-end body tag
  function class_to_body($classes) {
    global $current_user;
    $user_role = array_shift($current_user->roles);
    $classes[] = $user_role.' ';
  return $classes;
 }

  /// Add user role class and user id 
  /// add 'class-name' to the $classes array
      function class_to_body_admin($classes) {
        global $current_user;
        $user_role = array_shift($current_user->roles);
       
      /* Adds the user id to the admin / backend body class array */
       $user_ID = $current_user->ID;
       $classes = $user_role.' '.'user-id-'.$user_ID ;
      return $classes;
     return 'user-id-'.$user_ID;
    }
```

Comment: The use of `array_shift` in the `admin_body_class` filter here causes a conflict with Woocommerce where the Administrator user role disappears. Using `$current_user->roles[0]` instead fixes that issue.

Comment: Also, why are you returning twice in the `class_to_body_admin` function? There is no case in which the second return will ever be triggered.

Comment: Also, in the `class_to_body_admin` function, you should be appending the string to the `$classes` variable, not overwriting it:
`$classes .= $user_role.' '.'user-id-'.$user_ID;`

Answer (score -2):

Similarly, if you wanted to add the user-id to the body class in the backend, you'd use:

```
/* Adds the user id to the admin body class array */
add_filter('admin_body_class', 'add_username_to_body');
function add_username_to_body( $classes ) {
    // add 'class-name' to the $classes array
    global $current_user;
    $user_ID = $current_user->ID;
    $classes[] = 'user-id-' . $user_ID;
    // return the $classes array
    return 'user-id-'.$user_ID;
}
```

Comment: The user is asking for a role.